# How to publish Test Only Objects in a sbt project

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have been developing a common library for my team, where I need to provide mock data for end users to write unit-test code. Ideally, the mock object should only be available to tests of packages referencing mine, but I am not sure how to do this.

My package structure is:

```
├── common
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── scala
│   │   └── test
│   │       ├── resources
│   │       └── scala
│   │           └── MockData.scala // <--- object defined here
├── build.sbt
```

In my build.sbt, I have

```
Test / publishArtifact := true
Test / publish := true

packageBin / publishArtifact := true
```

And I use `sbt clean; sbt compile; sbt publishLocal` to publish my library locally.

In the project referencing the above library, I added the following to the build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.my" %% "common" % "0.0.1",
  "org.my" %% "common" % "0.0.1" % Test,
)
```

but when writing tests, I cannot find objects defined in MockData.scala.

Please provide some hints, much appreciated.

------------------ UPDATE ------------------

After googling around, I'd decided to write a separate module for publishing test data only. So my package structure becomes:

```
├── common
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── scala
│   │   └── test
│   │       ├── resources
│   │       └── scala
├── common-testkit
│   ├── src
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── resources
│   │       └── scala
│   │           └── MockData.scala // <--- object defined here
├── build.sbt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the way you ask to retrieve the test code in your other project.

`"org.my" %% "common" % "0.0.1" % Test` means to depends on the "main" code of project common when running the tests of your other project. That's what the scope `Test` (after the version) means.

What you want is to depend on the "test code" of common project when running your tests. This is done by specifying what is called a "classifier" in sbt:

```scala
"org.my" %% "common" % "0.0.1" % Test classifier "tests"
```